# Finding the Jacobian Matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-transformations, jacobian

**Question**: Find the Jacobian matrix of the differentiable function, $ f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by $ f(x) = \langle Ax, x \rangle $, where $ A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is a linear transformation.

**My approach:**

I computed the derivative linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ denoted by $df_x(h)$ = $\langle Ax, h \rangle$ + $\langle Ah, x \rangle$

but i am not able to proceed from here on how to calculate the jacobian matrix. i am having trouble on getting the matrix of this linear transformation  with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: Don't we need to have $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for the inner product to be defined?

Comment: yeah, you are right, typo corrected.

Comment: $\langle Ax, x \rangle = x^TAx$ with $x^T$ the transpose of $x$.